# How to redirect according to URL parameter after form submission

Tags: forms, redirection, users

Currently I'm using Drupal as my authentication system, and I would like to redirect user to our main site after login, according to an URL-passed parameter, for example user/login?redir=http://google.com. And yes I've found out there is a destination parameter however it doesn't work it the passed argument begins with http or somehow a non-Drupal path. Any ideas? [hook_drupal_goto_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_drupal_goto_alter/7) is a hook I found might be helpful, but not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with `?destination=` is that it provides no mechanism for setting `external => TRUE` for the options in `drupal_goto()`, which Drupal needs to redirect to an off-site location.

I think the easiest way to get what you're looking for is to implement `hook_form_alter()` for the user login form, save the URL parameter if it's available, and then manually redirect in the submit handler.

Something like this:

```
function MYMODULE_form_user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($_GET['redir'])) {
    $form['redir'] = array(
      '#type' => 'value',
      '#value' => $_GET['redir']
    );

    $form['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULE_user_login_redirect';
  }
}

function MYMODULE_user_login_redirect(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = array($form_state['values']['redir'], array('external' => TRUE));
}
```

Comment: you should know better. Use $form_state['redirect']

Comment: @googletorp Not sure what happened there :/ In my defence that was quite near my birthday so I may have been drunk ;)